# Add more button at the end of text inside UITextView Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uibutton, uitextview

I am trying to do something similar to the one in this link http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/mobile/pattern/img/expand-collpase-description.png

Expanding the content inside a UITextView when clicking the button 'more'. I am creating the button in my viewDidLoad like the below

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"more" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.detailPriceView addSubview:button];
```

I am setting the frame of the button inside the UITextView after loading the data from PFQuery

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.restaurantName];
    [query whereKey:@"ItemName" equalTo:self.item_name];

    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *itemDataObj, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            self.detailPriceView.text = [itemDataObj objectForKey:@"PriceDetail"];

            self.detailPriceView.text = [self.detailPriceView.text substringToIndex:40];

            [button setFrame:self.detailPriceView.frame];
}
}];
```

How to add more button inside UITextView at the end of the text ? Also i created a constraint to increase it's height when the more button is clicked, but i'm unable to increase the constraint's height beyond some threshold size.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the same thing. Just add the button to textView.superView, because textView is scrollView. Use button's rect in textView as
`textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: rect)]`

At last, I did it. Most important thing is `rect` must be **included** in `textView.frame`.

Comment: For others' reference: `let rect = button.frame`

Comment: `button.frame` should be converted to `textView`'s coordination. @JustinVallely

Comment: Indeed it should. Good catch. I laid out the button in storyboard so I was already in that coordinate space. Thanks for adding clarification.

Comment: @DawnSong >  What text view coordinates should I put the button at?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how Apple implements it, but I can almost guarantee that it isn't a subview of the UITextView. How I would implement this feature would be to set up a custom container view for the UITextView. Set the default height for the container, and then if the UITextView's height is greater than the container view's height, display a more *UIButton* in the buttom right (or left, or top right, or wherever you want, bottom left seems to make the most sense) that simply animates the height of the container view to fit the UITextView.

If you really wanted to make it all in just a textview, I suppose you would have to subclass it to provide that kind of custom functionality, but someone else may know a way to do this all without subclassing UITextView. My approach would be the one described above.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll try and see if i can do it by extending UITextView. But how do i attach a button at the end of string text ? any idea ?

Comment: Shot answer: Don't. Create a view that contains both a text view and a button, and add logic in your view controller that positions the button based on the width of the text currently contained in the text view.