# How to Add a UIButton at the end of a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsstring

Could someone help me on how to add a `UIButton` at the end of a `NSString` ? I've tried doing:

`[self.mystring substringToIndex:25]` and again assigning

```
self.mystring.text = [self.mystring.text stringByAppendingString:@"...ReadMore"];
```

How can I make this 'ReadMore' as a `UIButton` ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You cannot put a UIButton at the end of a string. One object is data while the other is a UI component. You can place a button next to a textfield, label or text view but you will need to do this through the view hierarchy, not by simply manipulating the text

Comment: Hey Paulw11 thanks for the reply... i'm trying to do something like the one in this link http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/mobile/pattern/img/expand-collpase-description.png adding a 'more' button to the end of the NSString

Comment: i also asked a question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088565/add-more-button-at-the-end-of-text-inside-uitextview-objective-c

Comment: Right, well you have the answer in that question.  You can't put a button into a string. You need to have the button in the view hierarchy and use it to manipulate constraints on the UITextview

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 i'll try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier use UITapGestureRecognizer on a UITextView

```
- (IBAction)tapOnTextView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.textView];
    NSRange *range = [self.textView.text rangeOfString: @"...Read More"];
    UITextPosition *beginning = self.textView.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
    CGRect readMoreRect = [self.textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(readMoreRect,location)){
        //load more text or something
    }
}
```

You can use an attributed string to make ...Read More a different color so users know they can tap on it.